# How should I analyze and solve issues with web browsers?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, firefox

Currently I am getting pretty mad about "web-browsing" using my mac (os x 10.9).

Of course I tried all the major browser, like chrome, firefox and safari, but unfortunately they are driving me crazy.

In short, the problems I am face with:

- Safari: Scrolling keeps stopping, the "swipe back"-function breaks the current tab. And the textareas (with an editor - even this one here I´m typing my question in) keep crashing.
- Chrome: Scrolling keeps stopping. Tabs become frozen.
- Firefox: Mostly every feature (swipping, search using the "mainbar", etc.) is missing - the devtools are overloaded and far to complex for my needs

How can I analyze and fix these issues?

Comment: Do the problems still occur in a new user account?

Comment: From your description this seems to be more of a problem with your Mac (or some settings in your account at least) than with the browsers as such. As other people seem to not experience these problems, I've rewritten your question to focus more on solving these issues. Maybe you can add some specific scenarios in which you run into these issues (web sites, usage scenarios etc.)?

Comment: Well thanks for fixing! There is no special scenario, browsing a website, scrolling or using the swipe-back function often it´s working fine, but sometimes it breaks. In fact there are no fancy configurations made, I´m using the swipe gestures. You might google "chrome/safari/firefox stops scrolling mac" there are lots of people describing this situation, but not as many as this could be a "global issue". Maybe some had this issue and has a well working solution now? (e.g. https://discussions.apple.com/message/24102357#24102357)

Comment: I read this thread, but I don´t want to hack my mac by loading an touch-app or shutting-down the display every time, scrolling should be working by the os it self, doesn´t it?

Comment: @grgarside: Yes, I have 27" iMac and an equally configured MacBook Pro 13", this occurs on both machines.